# Function apply with arguments using slice

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, angularjs, slice

Looking at this [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-a-web-app-from-scratch-in-angularjs/) I saw the following code suggestion in one comment:

```
init:function(callback){
            var that =this ;
            return $http.jsonp(this.url).success(
                function(data){
                    that.availableGenres = that.getGenres(data);
                    that.results = that.getResults(data);
                    if(callback)callback.apply(null,[].slice.call(arguments))
                }
            )
        }
```

But this line `callback.apply(null,[].slice.call(arguments))` looks weird to me.

Why not just: `callback.apply(null, arguments)`? Because I don't like when I don't understand the point of something I played around with this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UdjqE/) to understand the need of `slice` function in there. But it gives me the same result and I still do not get it.

Anyone knows why `slice` is needed?

Comment: apply() likely expects the second parameter to have the .pop() method, however arguments does not have this method because it's not a real array

Comment: @Eru: No. It only expects it to have a `.length` property, nothing else.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't really need it, passing [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) to [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) directly is fine.

It is specified to be allowed in [EcmaScript 3](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-15.3.4.3), and [EcmaScript 5](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.3) even allows any array-like objects not only arrays and arguments objects. Maybe it was needed to be backwards-compatible with even earlier or buggy JS implementations. Also, (as you see from the other answers), some people don't know about this fact and think they would need to pass actual arrays - so they are unnecessary careful.

Comment: thanks. that makes sense. maybe earlier versions of IE need that

Comment: @letiagoalves: Yes, that's what I had assumed as well, but I cannot find any evidence on the web

Comment: I also found no evidence on the web. But I've verified that passing `arguments` to `apply` works at least in IE9 (using browserstack live). I ran `var fn = function() { return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join('---'); }; (function() { return fn.apply(null, arguments); })(1,'a',true,{},[],function(){},/.*/);` in the console, and it returned `"1---a---true---[object Object]------function(){}---/.*/"`.

Comment: Verified on IE8 as well (lucky me supporting IE8 in 2016 :S). You can pass `arguments` directly to `apply` :).

Answer (score 2):

slice is needed because function.apply requires an array, [arguments is not a real array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) but can be converted to one using slice.

> The arguments object is not an Array. It is similar to an Array, but
>   does not have any Array properties except length. For example, it does
>   not have the pop method. However it can be converted to a real Array:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

this is one of the ugly parts of javascript

Comment: Why would a `pop` method be necessary?