# when did arguments become a real array inside JS functions

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

Historically, we had to do:

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
fn.apply(this, args);
```

to grab actual function call arguments and pass them to [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). However, since some time, I can see that arguments object *does* have slice method available, hence above snippet is not required anymore.

The question is - when did it change, what was it, a specification update?

---

edit: I was unclear above... I mean that `fn.apply(this, arguments)` does work (I checked in latest chrome and firefox):

```
function add(a,b){
  return a + b;
}

function whatever(){
  return add.apply(null, arguments)
}

whatever(2,3) // 5
```

in other words, `arguments` can be now used within apply directly. Some time ago, it didn't work, it had to be passed to Array.prototype.slice.apply as above.

Comment: Actually it is now easier. `Array.from(arguments)` with new ES2016 :)

Comment: @TolgahanAlbayrak cool, but the question is different ;)

Comment: There's no `arguments.slice()` for me in Firefox.

Comment: It mustn't be a spec, because it doesn't work on my chrome: `(function() { return arguments.slice })()` returns undefined.

Comment: Also you shouldn't use that anyway if you care about just-in-time optimization.

Comment: However, this loses its utility in ECMA6, with the advent of the Rest (splat) operator.

Comment: @ducin sorry for that. btw it works when you apply arguments directly `fn.apply(this, arguments)`

Comment: It is not the case that `arguments` is an array.  It's just that those methods work for *array-like objects*: objects with a  `.length` property and properties with integer names.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function apply with arguments using slice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20373819/function-apply-with-arguments-using-slice)

Comment: You never mentioned slice in your code and yet you are saying **arguments can be now used within slice directly**

Comment: @GangadharJannu you're right, my bad, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

It isn't.

Try the following:

```
var foo = function() {
  console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments)); 
};

foo(); // [object Arguments]

console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call([])); // [object Array]
```

Note that the difference between arrays and objects is a little fuzzy in JS-land:

```
var foo = { "0": 1, "1": 2 };
Object.defineProperty(foo, "length", {
  value: 2
});
```

`foo` will now work with a surprising number of array methods using `call`, `apply`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No it didn't.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

> The arguments **object** is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.

Example: We want to return the arguments passed to function as an array

Below code throws error because we are directly calling `slice` method on `arguments`  Array-like object.

```
function fun(){
    // throws error arguments.slice is not function
    return arguments.slice(0); 
}
```

Below works expected as we are converting `Array-like object to Array`

```
function fun(){
    // returns the arguments as array
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)
}
```